# catch sequencial of folder name in php

Tags: php

So, i heave in the master directory this: temp_1,temp_2,temp_3.
All this folders are temporary, and after i rename to other name. 
Ok until now everything works fine.I use responsive filemanager in last version to do this, 
and i want to hidden the folders temporary until the renamed, 
in msdos for example i can use "*.txt" to select all text files ignorig the name, or "file.*" to all files ignoring the extension, but in php or html how to do that?
I heave this on config.php of responsive filemanager 
in config.php of responsive filemanager i heave this:

```
'hidden_folders'                          => array(),
```

if i try this:

```
'hidden_folders'                          => array("temp_1"),
```

works but only to one folder, i need hidden all folders that have a name beginning with temp_

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but maybe the `glob()` function is what you're looking for?

Comment: so, i search for some way to hidden all folder with name temp_xxx, where xxx is a random number. i tryed with glob() but doesnt work.

Comment: i edited the question, maybe now are more easy to understand me.

Answer (score 0):

The `glob()` function can be used to match a wildcard pattern.

```
'hidden_folders' => glob('temp_*'),
```

Comment: i tryed:

 'hidden_folders' => array(glob('temp_*')),

and:

'hidden_folders'   => (glob('temp_*'),

but not work

Comment: This will get the list of matching names when the config.php file is loaded. If you need it to update dynamically, you'll have to reassign it whenever necessary.

Comment: There's no way to make an array automatically track the file changes.

Comment: how i do that? can you help me?

Comment: Add code to your application to do something like `$config['hidden_folders'] = glob('temp_*');` whenever it creates or deletes temp files.